# Openshift access to phpMyAdmin?

Tags: openshift

How do i access phpMyAdmin using openshift?

I'v just set up a new openshift account today and I really have no idea what I'm doing.
I'v added Node.js, MySQL 5.5 and phpMyAdmin 4.0.

With other web hosting services I could get to the phpMyAdmin user interface with the click of a button but with openshift... I don't see any button...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have added `phpMyAdmin` and if you can see it under your application, you will be able to access it using this url;

`https://XXXXX-XXXXX.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/`

replace `XXXXX-XXXXX` as per your url.

If you haven't changed the default's, `phpMyAdmin` uses same username password which you use for `MySql`.

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks Mohammad :D

Comment: how to hide or change phpmyadmin to something random for security purpose

Comment: What about the new 'OpenShift Online3 Starter' ?